# Why can't we use reverse side of ForeignKey relationship in a Django Form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm running into a problem when using a `ModelForm` and I want to know if I'm crazy or not before I go off making some complicated work-around

**Use Case**:

I have the following model definitions:

```
class Setting(models.Model):
    """Manufacturing settings - can be shared among materials to be manufactured"""
    ...

class Material(models.Model):
    """Specific record for a material that is manufactured"""
    ...
    setting = models.ForeignKey('Setting', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='materials')

class ManufacturingRun(models.Model):
    """An instance of a manufacturing run"""
    material = models.ForeignKey('Material', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='manufacturing_runs')
```

In this application, the data in the Material model is coming from an outside source and we do not provide users the ability to edit these records.  However, the `setting_id` field is *not* populated as part of the data received from this outside source.

Basically I need my users to define `Setting` instances and be able to assign each record to multiple Material instances.  To that end I define a `Setting` form like so:

```
class SettingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Setting
      fields = [
        ...
        'materials'
      ]
```

**Problem:**
Everything seems fine until I access the `View` to create a new `Setting`, thereby triggering the instantiation of a `SettingForm` object.  The server returns

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (materials) specified for Setting
```

I've become so used to the flexibility of Django's ORM I a somewhat baffled here.  I guess I don't see why this cannot be handled in the same way M2M relationships are in forms.  Despite the fact that the `_id` field exists in neither model on either side of an M2M field, we can use related names just fine when defining forms.

I have occasionally built very complex work-arounds before finding some ridiculously simple methods in the ORM to achieve similar results so I wanted to reach out before I start coding some brittle and complicated mess that I will fear to touch in 6 months.